# Compare and update a table from another database : "must be appear in the group by" error

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to update a table of a database (table 1) with an other table (same columns) in other database (table 2). The only constraint is to get entries in table 2 with `id`s higher than the maximum `id` in table 1. Bonus: afterwards, can we delete the columns inserted in table 1 from table 2 the same instruction?

Table 1:

```
id | title 
1  | Hi, I'm first here :)
```

Table 2:

```
id | title 
1  | Hi, I'm a data ! 
2  | hehe I'm second row ! 
3  | Wait me, I'm 3 ! 
4  | Hi friends, I'm 4
```

What I try to have:

Table 1:

```
id | title 
1  | Hi, I'm first here :) 
2  | hehe I'm second row ! 
3  | Wait me, I'm 3 ! 
4  | Hi friends, I'm 4
```

Table 2:

```
id | title 
1  | Hi, I'm a data !
```

Request

```
SELECT
    test_dblink_reception.id,
    requete.id,
    requete.title
FROM
    test_dblink_reception,
    dblink('host=myhost user=user password=password dbname=database2', 'SELECT id, title FROM test_dblink_emission') AS requete (id int,
        title text)
GROUP BY
    test_dblink_reception.id,
    requete.id,
    requete.title
HAVING
    max(test_dblink_reception.id) < requete.id
```

This returns

```
id | id | title
1  | 2  | hehe I'm second row !
1  | 3  | Wait me, I'm 3 !
1  | 4  | Hi friends, I'm 4
```

We have rows, but if in the `GROUP BY` instruction I delete test_dblink_reception.id to insert, Postgres say must be appear in the group by clause. How to fix that?

Is it possible to delete rows from table 2 after insert?

Answer (score 0):

Since this affects several databases, you can't well do it in a single statement.
One statement can only affect a single database. You could use a foreign table to get around this, but I don't see the point.

I would proceed like this:

1. In database 1:

   ```
   SELECT max(id) FROM table_1;
   ```
2. Assuming the result is 4711, run the following in database 2:

   ```
   DELETE FROM table_2 WHERE id > 4711 RETURNING *;
   ```
3. Iterate through the results and insert them in `table_1` on the first database.